# Storing images for offline support in cordova app

Tags: cordova

currently i am storing  images as base64 string localy in my cordova app inside a sqlite database to get offline support. Does anyone know if it is better/faster to store them as file with the cordova-plugin-file? Or ist there a better way to store images for offline support? Any advice or experiences in that topic? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you are using the images and how important performance is to you.

In my own Cordova-based apps, I'm downloading map tile images for offline use and using HTML5 canvas to display them. 
So in my case, performance is important to ensure that pinch-zooming/panning of the map is smooth.

In my solution I use [cordova-plugin-file-transfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) to download a zip containing the images to `cordova.file.cacheDirectory` (see [cordova-plugin-file directories](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#where-to-store-files)). Then I unzip it to `cordova.file.dataDirectory` using [cordova-plugin-zip](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-zip). My app reads the image data from file by creating `new Image()` objects in Javascript and setting the `src` attribute to the local path of images within `cordova.file.dataDirectory`. I then use the [HTML5 Canvas `drawImage()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) to copy the image data to the canvas.
The performance of this process is highly efficient, giving smooth panning/zooming of map tiles on Android and iOS devices.

However, due to lack of support for the `file://` protocol in iOS's WKWebView, I am forced to continue using UIWebView for my apps on iOS (no `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` for me).
I have tried a few workarounds for WKWebView, including reading images via the local webserver bundled with the WKWebView plugin (i.e. `http://localhost:8080/path/to/myimage.png`), reading images as an array buffer via `cordova-plugin-file` and reading images as an base-64 via `cordova-plugin-file`, but all have proven unperformant to the point the map becomes unusable.

My suspicion is that your technique of storing and retrieving image data from a SQLite DB is also not performant - storing blobs of binary data is not what SQL databases were designed for.
However, performance may not be so much of an issue in your case, so your solution may suffice.

Comment: Thank you. I am storing maptiles for offline use as well. The App is downloading the maptiles from a WMTS and stores the tiles in a slite db via the cordova-sqlite-ext plugin which has support for cordova android and ios.

I modiefed the "tileLoadFunction" of the map client which checks whether the tile is available offline or not before a request is send to the WMTS. This works quiet perfomant and i can add/store some additional properties to each tile like a timestamp which gives me the necessary information to refresh the tiles after an specific time.

Comment: So far is the performance of the map (panning/zooming) good and the possiblity to refresh older tiles is in my case necessary. For the offline storage of my maptiles i will go with the sqlite-plugin, but for all other Images i will try the file plugin

Comment: sorry to hijack this a little bit but are you downloading a new sqlite db file or just a collection of images then inserting them into the sqlite db